# Как предать данные конкретного контейнера?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет. Циклом foreach подгружаю из базы данных посты как на примере: "пост 1" "пост 2" "пост 3" и тд.

```
        //---------------*  Цикл подгрузки постов *---------------//

        foreach($b['response'] as $value) :
        if (!$value['text']) continue;

        ?>
        <form method="post" action="parser.php">


              <div class="horisontal-container">
                 <div class="full-block-1">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" value="<? $title = explode(".", $text_clean)[0]; echo $title;  ?>" size="48"><!--explode — Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя-->
                    <div class="photo"> 
                        <? for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) { // переберает фотографии ?> 
                       <img class="img_content" style="background-image: url(<?= $value['attachments'][$i]['photo']['src_big']?>);">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="full-block-2">
                    <textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" placeholder="Описание" ><? echo  $text_clean; ?></textarea>
                 </div>
                 <div class="vertical-container">
                    <div class="row-item-1"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" value="<? echo $first_name ?>" size="30"> </div>
                    <div class="row-item-2"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="id профиля" value="vk.com/id<?= strip_tags ($value['signer_id']); ?>" size="30"></div>
                    <div class="row-item-2"><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" value="<? echo $phone ?>" size="30"> </div>
                    <div class="row-item-2"><input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Цена" value="<? echo $price ?>" size="30"> </div>
                    <div class="row-item-2"><input  type="text" name="region" placeholder="Город" disabled="disabled" value="<? echo $city ?>" size="30"> </div>



        <?
        //---------------*  Подгрузка городов из БД *---------------//



          $sql_region = "SELECT * FROM `regions`";
          $result_select = mysqli_query($on_link, $sql_region);
            echo "<select class='row-item-2' name = 'region'>";
            echo "<option value='0'>Город</option>";                             
                while($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result_select)){
                    echo "<option value = '$object->id' > $object->name </option>";
                }
            echo "</select>";



        //---------------*  Подгрузка Категорий из БД *---------------//
            echo $cat;


        ?>


        <!--------------------- Блок с кнопками --------------------------->

           </div>
                 <div class="vertical-container buttom-block">
                    <a href="#" type="buttom" class="buttom">Отправить на сайт</a>
                    <a href="#" class="buttom-delete" onclick="return deleteRow(this)">Удалить</a>
                 </div>
                 <hr align="center" width="95%" size="1" color="grey" />
              </div>




        <!--------------------- Конец цикла --------------------------->

        <?php endforeach; ?>


        ?>

    //---------------*  Отправка в  БД *---------------//


<script>
    $( '[type="buttom"]' ).click(function() {

$.post( "submit.php", {
    title: $( '[name="title"]' ).val(),
    text: $( '[name="text"]' ).val(),
    name: $( '[name="name"]' ).val(),
    email: $( '[name="email"]' ).val(),
    phone: $( '[name="phone"]' ).val(),
    price: $( '[name="price"]' ).val(),
    region: $( '[name="region"]' ).val(),
    cat: $( '[name="cat"]' ).val() 

},
       function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});




});
</script>


        ?>
```

Как лучше всего сделать чтобы кнопка "отправить" отправляла только те данные которые находятся в ее контейнере ?  Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.buttom', function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var self = btn.closest('form');
    var fields = new Object();


    fields.title = self.find('input[name="title"]').val();
    fields.text = self.find('input[name="text"]').val();
    fields.name = self.find('input[name="name"]').val();
    fields.email = self.find('input[name="email"]').val();
    fields.phone = self.find('input[name="phone"]').val();
    fields.price = self.find('input[name="price"]').val();
    fields.region = self.find('input[name="region"]').val();
    fields.cat = self.find('input[name="cat"]').val();

    $.post('submit.php', fields, function(json) {
        console.log('json', json);
        console.log('fields', fields);
    });

});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как подправить, у меня "text" не в "input" в  теге "<textarea> "?

Comment: вместо input -> textarea

fields.message = self.find('textarea[name="message"]').val();

message - это ваш name в поле формы

Comment: Большое спасибо. Может подскажите сразу, как после отправки сделать кнопку не активной.

Comment: Вы мой код используете?

Comment: btn.prop('disabled', true); - Кнопка заблокирована будет

Comment: btn.prop('disabled', false); - Разблокировать

Comment: Только сделайте кнопку - кнопкой <button type="button" class="button">Кнопка</button> - а то у вас ссылкой кнопка

Comment: Потом это $(document).on('click', 'a.buttom' замените на $(document).on('click', '.buttom'

Comment: Да, использую ваш код. Спасибо!